# Why Google Play Services doesn't appears after installed

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have installed google play through Android SDK Manager, but it doesn't appears on my project list.
[image]

Logcat doesn't show anything.
Someone knows what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It won't automatically appear in your project list/workspace. You'll have to manually import it.

So right click in your package explorer, import > Existing Project into workspace > Browse the root directory and import.

You'll find the lib in sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib